# Regex matches in myregexp.com, but not matching in Java

Tags: java, regex

This is the regex for finding the session ID: "(?<=( ))([0-9]*)(?=(.*ABC.*DEEP.*   [1-9] s))" and the output is:

```
    ID     TYPE    USER                            IDLE

    63494  ABC     DEEP                            3 s
 -> 70403  ABC     DEEAP                           0 s
    82446  ABC     DEEOP                           52 min 27 s
```

In myregexp.com/signedJar.html, this regex works fine. But when I try to find using Java, it is not able to get the output. Please find the snippet:

```
    FrameworkControls.regularExpressionPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=( ))([0-9]*)(?=(.*ABC.*DEEP.*[1-9] s))");
    String deepak = "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    ID     TYPE    USER                            IDLE\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    63494  ABC     DEEP                            3 s\n" +
            " -> 70403  ABC     DEEAP                           0 s\n" +
            "    82446  ABC     DEEOP                           52 min 27 s\n";

    FrameworkControls.regularExpressionMatcher = FrameworkControls.regularExpressionPattern.matcher(deepak);


    if (FrameworkControls.regularExpressionMatcher.find()) {
        String h = FrameworkControls.regularExpressionMatcher.group().trim();
        System.err.println(h);
    }
```

"FrameworkControls.regularExpressionMatcher.find()" returns true. But h variable is always empty. Can anyone let me know, where I might be doing wrong.

Expected Output: 63494

Comment: Maybe the top statement on the site might explain something: `This is sandbox to test JavaScript regular expression. To test JAVA regular expression you can use java-applet`

Comment: @N Deepak did you want the second line?

Comment: @Eypros, I am using Java-Applet only. Please check the link, I have shared.

Comment: which id you want to be printed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to print  ID of the USER DEEPAK. If yes, then your code would be,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<= )[0-9]+(?=\\s*ABC\\s*DEEP\\s*[0-9]\\s*s)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(deepak);
while (m.find()) {
System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/hwpe4d)

Comment: I want to print 63494

Comment: It prints the input plus 63494. See the ideone link.

Comment: did you want `63494` to be printed?, then remove the `System.out.println(deepak);` line from the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following expression:

```
"^\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+).+\$"
```

then

```
group(1) is ID
group(2) is TYPE
group(3) is USER
```

The expressions are non greedy, so you can remove last two groups if you don't need them.